# How to check in a file if the string with another string exists in file?

Tags: python

How to check in file if the string exists and some string is next to it.
To be precise, I have the following code:

```
with open ('CTF.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        strings = (validationforvote, "voted")
            for line in myfile:
               if any(s in line for s in strings):
                print "you cannot vote twice"
myfile.close()
```

I am storing four digit number in validationforvote(variable) and want to check it there is a string with "voted" next to validationforvote in file. Currently I have in file:

```
9779 voted
8568 voted
```

If I input again 9779 as validationforvote, it has to search in this file if this exists and if there is "voted" next to it. If yes, it has to tell the user, you cannot vote twice.
Currently mode code is not executing as it should be:

Comment: using validationforvote I am storing the validation numbers into this file and marking it as voted after the user votes it. Now after the second input, it should check if the validationforvote already exists with voted next to it..

Comment: `strings = (validationforvote + " voted")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues.

> First is that your `if` statement is checking if `validationforvote` or `voted` is in the line, that is preventing your code from functioning as you expect.
>
> Second, if you open a file using `with open(...) as myfile`, you do not have to close it after the block.
>
> Third, using a tuple to store the `validationforvote` and the literal `'voted'` is a bit unnecessary.

Cleaning things up a bit, you can use the following:

```
with open ('CTF.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if line.strip() == "{} voted" % (validationforvote):
            print "you cannot vote twice"
```

Comment: Use new string formatting "{} voted".format(validationforvote)

Answer (score 1):

If your data is structured just like in your example you can do this:

```
with open("myfile") as open_file:  
    # read the file and split it on each newline
    f=open_file.read().split('\n')

for line in f:
    # check if any of the lines start with validationforvote
    # and has allready voted  
    if validationforvote == line[:4] and 'voted' == line[5:]:
        print("You cannot vote twice!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use regular expression operations:

```
import re
with open ('CTF.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    result=re.search(str(validationforvote)+' voted$', myfile.read())
    if result:
        print "you cannot vote twice"
    myfile.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently, it'll print if *either* validationforvote *or* 'voted' is in the line- which means every time 'voted' is there, it prints. Your conditional should be more like:

```
if (" ".join(strings) in line):
```

So it constructs the thing you're looking for, i.e. `"9779 voted"` as the exact string to look for, and then sees if that is in the line (you could also do ==, but then you have to account for the newline)